# R Shiny Reactively Source Functions

Tags: r, shiny

How can I reactively / dynamically source functions within my Shiny app, and clear / remove any objects that have been sourced / stored in my environment if the user selects another input? For example, if I have the following directory structure in my project:

```
test/app/app.R
test/Dummy_Folder/Functions/myFunc.R
test/Dummy_Folder/Functions/otherFunc.R
test/Test_Folder/Functions/anotherFunc.R
test/Test_Folder/Functions/otterFunc.R
```

I would want to source all functions within the "Dummy_Folder" **OR** the "Test_Folder" depending on what the user selects. Here is a sample code that is breaking for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "sel.folder", label = "Select a folder:", selected = "BCRM_AM_RK_11_MUNI_B0",
              # identifies folders for selection
              choices = c(dir("../")[which(!(dir("../") %in% c("app")))])),
  textOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # shows which files/functions are available to source within the directory
  files = reactive({
    
    list.files(here::here(input$sel.folder, "Functions"))
    
  })
  
  observe({
    
    for (i in files()) {
      
      source(here::here(input$sel.folder, "Functions", i))
      
    }
    
  })

  
  # outputs True / False depending if the function has been successfully sourced
  output$test = renderText({ exists("myFunc") })
  
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can't have the `for (i in 1:files())` loop outside a reactive context. When do you want to source the files? If it's on input change, then user an `observe` rather than `reactive` to source the files. Also, you can't "un-source" files so I'm not sure what you want to happen when the input value changes from one value to the other.

Comment: @MrFlick I tried wrapping it in observe before, but it didn't work for me. I updated the example above to reflect the observe. The "exist" output does not pick up the function after it is sourced.

Comment: @MrFlick sorry, I just realized I made a syntax error, your suggestion did the trick, thank you! Is there a way to un-source / clear the environment? Such as "rm(list = ls())"?

Comment: No. Sourcing a file has side effects that you cannot easilt undo unless you make a lot of assumptions about that's in the file. Conditionally sourcing a file is not a good design idea. Preferably you would just source all your files at once and maintain some state in your application that dispatches to the correct functions.